# Opening office documents in SP Library crashes in (VM) WServer08 R2, but works fine on host

Tags: library, office

I have a development environment set up in VMWare - host OS is Windows 7 x64, guest OS is Windows Server 2008 r2. Browser used by both OS is IE 9 32 bit, addons enabled, intranet comptability mode disabled. Whenever i invoke an action in the Sharepoint 2010-s UI, that has a dependency on the Office 2010 client app, for example editing a libraries document, prior to opening the document, the office crashes:

[image]

However editing and creating documents on the Guest's SPWeb (?) works fine on the Host OS, which has the exact same version of office installed, 32 bit Office 2010 Plus.

I have already enabled the WebClient windows service on the Guest along with different IE and Office settings (disabled Protected View).

Comment: Have you tried patching Office 2010 SP1 or greater?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yeah, but the update reports an error saying, i don't have the expected office installed. Link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26622

Comment: Does Windows Update give you the update for Office?  If not, just reinstall Office and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting OfficeFileCache folder which is located at :  c:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the Desktop Experience Windows feature on the server OS.

Comment: Word still crashes.